# Keep Headline and Table together

Tags: tables, minipage

I have a really strange behaviour on my latex file.

I want to display an Table and the headline (here a `paragraph`) on the same page. So far I used always the `minipage` workaround for this. But for the `table` its for some reason not working.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}



    \begin{minipage}[!hb]{\linewidth}

        \paragraph{my headline}

        \begin{center}
        \begin{table}[!h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lrccccc}
        \toprule
        bla & bla & bla & bla &  bla &  bla &   \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{blabla}
        \end{table}
        \end{center}

    \end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

how come that is is not working?

Comment: You can't have a floating environment (`table`) inside a `minipage`. If you need the caption, load the `caption` package and use `\captionof{table}{blabal}`.

Comment: You've also misused the optional argument for `minipage`. It can be *one* of `t`, `c`, `b`, and it indicates the vertical alignment of the `minipage` on the baseline. `!hb` is what you would use for a floating environment (`table`/`figure`), and is for indicating the allowed positions of the float on the page.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. thx with `\captionof` is working perfectly now. feel free to post this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `table` is a floating environment, and those cannot be used inside a `minipage` environment (nor does it make sense to have a float inside a `minipage`).  If you need the caption for the table, you can instead load the `caption` package, and use `\captionof{table}{...}`.

Note also that the (first) optional argument to a `minipage` can be one of `t` (top), `c` (center) or `b` (bottom), and it indicates the vertical alignment of the `minipage` on the current baseline.

Finally, because of paragraph indentation, the whole `minipage` is shifted to the right, and you get an *overfull hbox* warning in the log. Add `\noindent` before `\begin{minipage}` to fix that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}

% just to indicate the text boundaries
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}

        \paragraph{my headline}
        \begin{center}
        \captionof{table}{blabla}
        \begin{tabular}{lrccccc}
        \toprule
        bla & bla & bla & bla &  bla &  bla &   \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```